# Subsetting a dataframe conditional on minimum difference between 2 dates

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a dataframe with 4 variables: id, measurement, date_a, date_b.

A single id can contribute to the df more than once. I want to subset this dataframe to only include one measurement for each id. I want to select a single row for each id based on the minimum difference between date_b and date_a, however this minimum difference is required to be at least one year. Is there a way to do this using dplyr using one line of code rather than creating a new variable for the difference in dates?

Comment: Is this right: Show the single row per id with the smallest date difference that is at least one year? Are you looking for absolute date difference or does date_a always come first? Should we show zero rows if there are no differences greater than a year?

Comment: Hi Jon, yes I want to show a single row per id with the smallest date difference that is at least one year. The date difference will always be date_b minus date_a. If there are no rows with a minimum difference greater than one year for a specific id then all rows should be dropped from the new dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some fake data. (It's best practice to include something like this in your question to avoid ambiguity or misunderstandings about your particular situation.)

```
set.seed(8601)
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:3, each = 5),
  measurement = "foo",
  date_a = as.Date(sample(1:3000, 15), origin = "2010-01-01")
)
df$date_b <- df$date_a + sample(1:1000, 15)
```

Here's a slightly-longer-than-one-line approach with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(date_b-date_a >= 365) %>% filter(date_b-date_a == min(date_b-date_a))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
     id measurement date_a     date_b    
  <int> <fct>       <date>     <date>    
1     1 foo         2013-06-13 2014-11-26
2     2 foo         2014-10-05 2017-04-14
3     3 foo         2012-01-07 2014-02-11
```